# How can i set the path where my log files are stored while running the testcase in robot framework in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, automated-tests, robotframework, logfile

The project structure is shown in the image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDuzI.png)

when i run the test, robot framework by default is storing the output files at the folder shown by the white circle. But I desired folder where i need the output file to be stored is shown by the black circle. So, that I can keep my output files in each project folders separately.

So, any suggests what can i do here instead of setting the ${OUTPUT_DIR} inside the test setup ? Or how can i set that path from the testcase itself not from terminal?

As you can see in the image, I've already tried many ways to set that but its not working. I set the Suite variable ${OTUPUT_DIR} but its also not working. It is just setting the directory but the result are being stored at the folder with white circle.

Answer (score 1):

The output folder location is controlled by options passed to the `robot` script that you use to start test execution.

From User Guide:

```
-d, --outputdir <dir>
    Defines where to create output files.
```

pay attention to `-d` option in the next example

`python.exe -m robot -d c:\my_result -t Test1 C:\Users\NewProject`

more details you could get in UserGuide [6.2.1 Command Line options for test execution](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#command-line-options-for-test-execution)