# set the path of log,output,report and screenshots file to customized location

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I am using robot framework with selenium library.

I want to set the path of log,output,report and screenshots file to my customized location in my robot framework project.

without use bash robot command !

how can i do it?

Comment: Hmm, using options for the 'robot' command is the right way to customize the folder's location. Also, options could be set through environment variable `ROBOT_OPTIONS`. See [UserGuide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#robot-options-and-rebot-options-environment-variables). But just in case to clearly understand your case, could I ask you, why you requested not using parameters for `robot' command?

Comment: Because I want to give the project to someone with a low level of programming knowledge, and the log files will fill up the storage space.

Therefore, we want to keep all these files in a specific folder so that we can easily delete these files periodically. @SamMaksymyshyn

Comment: I mean passing custom location is very easy. For example, you use a command to run your test like: `python.exe -m robot -t my_test_name c:\path_to_my_tests`.  Then the option `-d path_to_folder` should be just added: `python.exe -m robot -d c:\my_result -t my_test_name c:\path_to_my_tests`.  See the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77086754/how-can-i-set-the-path-where-my-log-files-are-stored-while-running-the-testcase)